# For inputs of size n, for which values of n does insertion-sort beat merge-sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, mergesort, insertion-sort

In the book Introduction to Algorithms (Corman), exercise 1.2-2 asks a the following question about comparing  implementations of insertion sort and merge sort. For inputs of size n, insertion sort runs in 8n^2 steps while merge sort runs in 64n lg n steps; for which values of n does insertion sort beat merge sort?

Although I am interested in the answer, I am more interested in how to find the answer step by step (so that I can repeat the process to compare any two given algorithms if at all possible).

At first glance, this problem seems similar to something like finding the break even point in business-calculus, a class which I took more than 5 years ago, but I am not sure so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

P/S If my tags are incorrect, this question is incorrectly categorized, or some other convention is being abused here please limit the chastising to a minimum, as this is my first time posting a question.

Comment: The solution for `8n^2=64nlgn` is `n=44`. So for 43 or less elements use insertion sort, else use merge sort

Comment: @arunmoezhi do the figures 8n^2 and 64nlogn actually hold? Or are they just hypothetical values for the problem statement?

Comment: @zack problem stated those values.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Since you are to find when insertion sort beats merge sort

```
8n^2<=64nlogn
n^2<=8nlogn
n<=8logn
```

On solving `n-8logn = 0` you get

```
n = 43.411
```

So for `n<=43` insertion sort works better than merge sort.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I couldn't up-vote you because I do not a rep of +15. Up votes anyone? ;)

Comment: You can accept my answer by clicking on the green tick mark below the up votes.

Comment: Thank you sir, by the way can you tell me what the base of the log is? Super new to the material, which I am studying on my free time all alone.

Comment: To be honest I didn't get the ending completely, though I figured that was due to my forgetting nearly all of calculus (lol), so instead asking further about the math I reposted that portion of the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/977905/step-by-step-show-your-work-example-on-how-to-solve-a-log-problem-algebraicall) and was told the answer is incorrect, and I quote "It is not true : 43.11 > 8*log(43.11) = 30.11." Any ideas here?

Comment: It depends on the problem but in general The time complexity of merge sort is O(nlogn) and log base is 2. You can read about merge sort to understand why the base is 2.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I remember reading about that however this  discussion just put it into context for me. So if you don't mind, can you tell me how you got from n-8logn = 0 to the final answer of n = 43.411? Did you use the Lambert W function?

Comment: @NateNeuhaus I used Worlframalpha. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n-8*log%282%2Cn%29+%3D+0

Comment: Can you provide a step by step instructions to find n = 43.411 from 'n<=8lnn' equation?

Comment: @BexultanMyrzatayev There is no analytical solution to this. You could, for example, use Newton's method with a starting value of 50 to calculate the root of `f(x) = x - 8*log2(x)`. This series converges pretty quickly to a value of approx. 43.5.

Comment: @BexultanMyrzatayev Since this not an algebraic inequality, there isn't an analytical way to find a solution for `n`, so you need to approximate it. For instance, you can do it with a Python script. First, note that Python's `math.log` function is the `e` base logarithm, so you need to change the base 2 logarithm into base `e` logarithm via `log_2 (n) = log_e (n) / log_e (2)`. Then the original inequality becomes `n / log_e (n) <= 8 / log_e (2)`. Now do a `while (n/math.log(n)) <= 8/math.log (2)` and retrieve the value of `n` once the loop finishes. Round it down and that's your solution.